# What is a good MPEG-DASH encoding profile for live streaming wide screen videos?

Tags: video-streaming, video-encoding, mpeg-dash

I'm trying to come up with a sensible, hopefully optimal MPEG-DASH encoding profile for our existing mp4 files. I don't have any experience on this and I haven't found anything from googling. Can some one shed some light on this?

The videos don't move a lot, the scenes can be complex, I'm looking to help my users to have mobile 3G playbacks. I'm also expecting to have conventional resolutions(widescreen), namely of heights: 360/720/1080. In terms of source videos, they are mostly in 16:9 aspect ratio and majority of them came under 3500kbps.

Comment: There's not enough information here to adequately help you.  Besides, DASH doesn't have anything to do with encoding profiles, and aspect ratio has no bearing on bandwidth.  You should determine what sort of quality you expect for the program material, and set codec parameters in such a way that your specific audience can play your videos.  From your question, we don't know what's in the video (does it move a lot?  lots of complex scenes?), nor how much bandwidth your users have, nor the resolution of your source video.

Comment: I've updated my question as much as I can. Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an easy questions because it highly depends on the content, e.g., motion, resolution, input video bitrate, frame-rate etc.

In adaptive streaming systems like MPEG-DASH and HLS the first decision that needs to be made is: What is the minimum and maximum bitrate/resolution that the system should support. This depends of course on the resolution and bitrate of the input content and on the network conditions that most of your users are facing, e.g., mobile networks (3G, 4G) with bandwidth fluctuations from x to y and fixed networks with the same variances but in another range.

In general you could start with some standard encoding profiles. Apple offers some [general recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009745-CH1-SETTINGSFILES) for bitrates and resolutions that you should use with HLS. Afterwards when your system is live you could do some measurements, e.g., how much buffering do you see, what are the typical user bandwidths that you see, etc. and based on the observations you can tune your encoding profiles.

Answer (score 2):

Although the "optimal" encoding profile depends on the content itself, I can suggest the following configuration in general:

Codec: h264 Profile: High Bitrate: 4.8 Mbps Format: 1920 x 1080

Codec: h264 Profile: High Bitrate: 2.4 Mbps Format: 1280 x 720

Codec: h264 Profile: High Bitrate: 1.2 Mbps Format: 854  x 480

Codec: h264 Profile: High Bitrate: 800 kbps Format: 640  x 360

If you are limited with 3.5 Mbps by the input, you might want to skip the 1080p representation or simply use a lower bitrate. On mobile, it is also helpful to have an even lower representation ready - at least for some scenarios, like:

Codec: h264 Profile: High Bitrate: 400 kbps Format: 426 x 240

Another important aspect in context of MPEG-DASH, which you have to consider, is the segment length. More about choosing the right segments length, can for instance be found [here](https://bitmovin.com/mpeg-dash-hls-segment-length/).